# Change string on object

Tags: javascript, json

I have string what i get from Rest Api.

> "xfields":"year|1976||month|August||day|31||bithday|08/31/1976||age|41||zodiac-sing|Virgo||nationality|USA||occupation|Actress||sexual-orientation|Straight||eyes_color|Brown||hair-color|Black||height|168||heightft|5||heightin|6.1||weight|74||weightlbs|163||chest-size|102||chestsizeft|40||bra-size|40D||waist-size|70||waistsizeft|27||hips-size|98||hipssizeft|38||shoes-size|7||monhtdeath|January||img|2018-08/1533214206_shar-jackson-height-weight-body-measurements.jpg"

I do need change this string in to object like.

```
"xfields": {
   "year": "1976",
   "month": "August"
   //...
}
```

How i can do it? I know, i should use function .map() and .split(), but i don't know how do it better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Split by `||` to get an array of items and then split each of them by `|` to get key/value pairs.

Comment: Have you attempted anything in terms of solving this?

Comment: What browser do you need this to work in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do that by splitting the original string by `||` to get the pairs, and then iterate over it using `Array#reduce`.

In each iteration, split the pair again by `|` and assign the key/value to the result object.

```js
const string = "year|1976||month|August||day|31||bithday|08/31/1976||age|41||zodiac-sing|Virgo||nationality|USA||occupation|Actress||sexual-orientation|Straight||eyes_color|Brown||hair-color|Black||height|168||heightft|5||heightin|6.1||weight|74||weightlbs|163||chest-size|102||chestsizeft|40||bra-size|40D||waist-size|70||waistsizeft|27||hips-size|98||hipssizeft|38||shoes-size|7||monhtdeath|January||img|2018-08/1533214206_shar-jackson-height-weight-body-measurements.jpg";

const obj = string.split('||')
  .reduce((a, pairs) => {
    let [key, value] = pairs.split('|');
    a[key] = value;
    return a;
  }, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **reduce** method of array as follows

```
    let stringJson = `"xfields":"year|1976||month|August||day|31||bithday|08/31/1976||age|41||zodiac-sing|Virgo||nationality|USA||occupation|Actress||sexual-orientation|Straight||eyes_color|Brown||hair-color|Black||height|168||heightft|5||heightin|6.1||weight|74||weightlbs|163||chest-size|102||chestsizeft|40||bra-size|40D||waist-size|70||waistsizeft|27||hips-size|98||hipssizeft|38||shoes-size|7||monhtdeath|January||img|2018-08/1533214206_shar-jackson-height-weight-body-measurements.jpg"`;
stringJson = stringJson.split(":")[1].replace(/"/g, "");
const JSONobj = stringJson.split('||')
             .reduce((acc, pairs) => {
                let [key, value] = pairs.split('|');
                acc[key] = value;
                return acc;
             }, {});
console.log(JSONobj);
```

Or You can also use `forEach` method as follows

```
    let stringJson = `"xfields":"year|1976||month|August||day|31||bithday|08/31/1976||age|41||zodiac-sing|Virgo||nationality|USA||occupation|Actress||sexual-orientation|Straight||eyes_color|Brown||hair-color|Black||height|168||heightft|5||heightin|6.1||weight|74||weightlbs|163||chest-size|102||chestsizeft|40||bra-size|40D||waist-size|70||waistsizeft|27||hips-size|98||hipssizeft|38||shoes-size|7||monhtdeath|January||img|2018-08/1533214206_shar-jackson-height-weight-body-measurements.jpg"`;
    stringJson = stringJson.split(":")[1].replace(/"/g, "");
    const JSONobj =  {};
    stringJson.split('||')
    .forEach((pairs, index) => {
        let [key, value] = pairs.split('|');
        JSONobj[key] = value;
    });
    console.log(JSONobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.split()` to get an array and then using `array#map` convert array of key value array, then using `Object.assign` create a single object.

```js
const str = `"xfields":"year|1976||month|August||day|31||bithday|08/31/1976||age|41||zodiac-sing|Virgo||nationality|USA||occupation|Actress||sexual-orientation|Straight||eyes_color|Brown||hair-color|Black||height|168||heightft|5||heightin|6.1||weight|74||weightlbs|163||chest-size|102||chestsizeft|40||bra-size|40D||waist-size|70||waistsizeft|27||hips-size|98||hipssizeft|38||shoes-size|7||monhtdeath|January||img|2018-08/1533214206_shar-jackson-height-weight-body-measurements.jpg"`;
const obj = JSON.parse(`{${str}}`);
obj.xfields = Object.assign(...obj.xfields.split('||')
                 .map(s => { 
                    const [key,value] = s.split('|');
                    return {[key] : value};
                 }));
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex

```js
const myString = "year|1976||month|August||day|31||bithday|08/31/1976||age|41||zodiac-sing|Virgo||nationality|USA||occupation|Actress||sexual-orientation|Straight||eyes_color|Brown||hair-color|Black||height|168||heightft|5||heightin|6.1||weight|74||weightlbs|163||chest-size|102||chestsizeft|40||bra-size|40D||waist-size|70||waistsizeft|27||hips-size|98||hipssizeft|38||shoes-size|7||monhtdeath|January||img|2018-08/1533214206_shar-jackson-height-weight-body-measurements.jpg";

const myRegexp = /([^\|]*)\|([^\|]*)(?:\|\||$)/g;
match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
let result = {};
while (match != null) {
  result[match[1]] = match[2];
  match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
console.log(result)
```